# How to fix python dictionary output format

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have `data` `dict` like this :

```
data ={"tag": "hello", "patterns": "hello", "responses": "hi"}
```

and I store it in `file` but when i store in file `json.dumps(data)` that time it store in that format :

```
{'patterns': 'hello', 'tag': 'hello', 'responses': 'hi'}
```

how can i store data dictionary in this manner :

```
{"tag": "hello", "patterns": "hello", "responses": "hi"}
```

**My input is** :  `data ={"tag": "hello", "patterns": "hello", "responses": "hi"}`

**Output** : `{'patterns': 'hello', 'tag': 'hello', 'responses': 'hi'}`

**Required ouput** : `{"tag": "hello", "patterns": "hello", "responses": "hi"}`

Thank you!!

Comment: You mean you want to maintain the order of insertion?

Comment: @thefourtheye, I want to maintain order of insertion

Comment: In Python 2.x, dictionaries don't maintain any order. It internally uses a hash table to store the keys. So the order is entirely determined by the value of the hash. If the order is important, use lists/tuples or `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: @thefourtheye,Thank you , it is possible to do it by "collections.OrderedDict" ?

Comment: First of all, if the order is important, you should not maintain the data in the dictionary in the memory. You should use `OrderedDict` or a list. Yes, `OrderedDict` does maintain insertion order. But, when you are storing it in the file, you should store it as a list of key, value pairs. When the file is read, reconstruct the `OrderedDict` in memory.

Comment: @thefourtheye, I got it your point Thank you!!